# SQL Server MAX Date from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm in a bit of a jam and hoping someone here can point out the errors in my ways. I have an update that I wrote that has a case statement and if the case statement conditions I have an `ELSE` to get the max date from another table. I initially had it as `ELSE MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),vp.CancelDate,121)) END` and ran into as error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

I did some research and put it in a select statement and yet I'm still getting the same error.  I'm not doing this right obviously. Can someone please tell me how to get around this?

```
   SELECT CASE WHEN SFP.Product_Cancellation_Date__c IS NOT NULL AND cp.MainCode NOT IN ('AYE3','AYE4','AYE7') AND SFP.ABC_PRODUCT__c='AYE1' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),SFP.Product_Cancellation_Date__c ,121) 
            WHEN SFP.Product_Cancellation_Date__c IS NOT NULL AND cp.MainCode IN ('AYE3','AYE4','AYE7' ) AND SFP.ABC_PRODUCT__c='AYE2' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),SFP.Product_Cancellation_Date__c,121) 
     ELSE (select MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),vp.CancelDate,121)) from tblProducts) END --HERE IS WHERE MY ISSUE IS
     FROM [DB_User].[dbo].[Customer] s
    INNER JOIN [EMP].dbo.tblProducts vp ON vp.customerID=s.customerID
    INNER JOIN tblXXProducts cp ON vp.ProductID=cp.ProductID
    INNER JOIN [LINKEDSERVER].CBS.SF.tblRNRProduct__c SFP
    ON SFP.Account_Number__c=CAST(s.CustomerID AS VARCHAR)
    AND SFP.ABC_PRODUCT__c=CASE WHEN cp.MainCode IN ('AYE3','AYE4','AYE7' ) THEN 'XYZ' ELSE 'ERD' END
   WHERE s.Status='C' AND s.CustomerID='36598758';
```

Comment: Are you really getting the same error message even when you don't execute any `UPDATE` statements?

Comment: Hi Onkel, this is the error when I just run the select . "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: Alright, that seems more reasonable. Anyways, as @monah pointed out, you're selecting the `CancelDate` value from the wrong table. Something along the lines of `(SELECT MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), [p].[CancelDate], 121)) FROM [tblProducts] p)` might do the trick, but that depends on what you want to achieve within the `ELSE` statement.

Comment: Hi OnKel. If SFP.Product_Cancellation_Date__c is NULL then use the MAX cancel date in tbProducts that is tied to s.CustomerID='36598758'. That's basically all. But it seems harder than what I assumed.

Comment: @PeteMiller Update the question.  Question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

From reading your code

`select MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),vp.CancelDate,121)) from tblProducts`

here you should not use `vp.CancelDate` because you are trying to get the max from the `tblProducts` separately

I recommend you use the following:

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN SFP.Product_Cancellation_Date__c IS NOT NULL AND cp.MainCode NOT IN ('AYE3','AYE4','AYE7') AND SFP.ABC_PRODUCT__c='AYE1' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),SFP.Product_Cancellation_Date__c ,121) 
            WHEN SFP.Product_Cancellation_Date__c IS NOT NULL AND cp.MainCode IN ('AYE3','AYE4','AYE7' ) AND SFP.ABC_PRODUCT__c='AYE2' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),SFP.Product_Cancellation_Date__c,121) 
     ELSE x.CancelDate END 
     FROM [DB_User].[dbo].[Customer] s
    INNER JOIN [EMP].dbo.tblProducts vp ON vp.customerID=s.customerID
    INNER JOIN (
       (select MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),CancelDate,121)) as CancelDate from tblProducts)
    ) as x on vp.customerID = s.customerID
    INNER JOIN tblXXProducts cp ON vp.ProductID=cp.ProductID
    INNER JOIN [LINKEDSERVER].CBS.SF.tblRNRProduct__c SFP
    ON SFP.Account_Number__c=CAST(s.CustomerID AS VARCHAR)
    AND SFP.ABC_PRODUCT__c=CASE WHEN cp.MainCode IN ('AYE3','AYE4','AYE7' ) THEN 'XYZ' ELSE 'ERD' END
   WHERE s.Status='C' AND s.CustomerID='36598758';
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Hi Monah. when I change the code to that I get "No column name was specified for column 1 of 'x'."

Comment: yes sorry after the max statement add as CancelDate

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I think the following might work, even though it might not be the most efficient way of achieving what you want:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN [SFP].[Product_Cancellation_Date__c] IS NOT NULL
             AND [cp].[MainCode] NOT IN('AYE3', 'AYE4', 'AYE7')
             AND [SFP].[ABC_PRODUCT__c] = 'AYE1'
        THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), [SFP].[Product_Cancellation_Date__c], 121)
        WHEN [SFP].[Product_Cancellation_Date__c] IS NOT NULL
             AND [cp].[MainCode] IN('AYE3', 'AYE4', 'AYE7')
             AND [SFP].[ABC_PRODUCT__c] = 'AYE2'
        THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), [SFP].[Product_Cancellation_Date__c], 121)
        ELSE
             (SELECT 
                  MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), [p].[CancelDate], 121))
              FROM [tblProducts] [p]
              WHERE [p].[customerID] = [s].[customerID])
    END --HERE IS WHERE MY ISSUE IS
FROM [DB_User].[dbo].[Customer] [s]
INNER JOIN [EMP].[dbo].[tblProducts] [vp]
     ON [vp].[customerID] = [s].[customerID]
INNER JOIN [tblXXProducts] [cp]
     ON [vp].[ProductID] = [cp].[ProductID]
INNER JOIN [LINKEDSERVER].[CBS].[SF].[tblRNRProduct__c] [SFP]
     ON [SFP].[Account_Number__c] = CAST([s].[CustomerID] AS VARCHAR)
        AND [SFP].[ABC_PRODUCT__c] = CASE
                                         WHEN [cp].[MainCode] IN('AYE3', 'AYE4', 'AYE7')
                                         THEN 'XYZ'
                                         ELSE 'ERD'
                                     END
WHERE [s].[Status] = 'C'
      AND [s].[CustomerID] = '36598758';
```

Note that in the `SELECT` statement you're retrieving the `MAX` value for the `CancelDate` column for every customer you're selecting in your overall query, which in your case will only be the customer with the ID value of 36598758 due to the final `WHERE` statement.

This is of course untested since I don't have the `CREATE TABLE` statements and some initial data.

Comment: Onkel after tweaking the code a little that got me on my way. Thank you very much for taking the time to help troubleshooting!!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cross tables like this
I am surprised you are even getting as far as a multiple rows error

```
select MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), vp.CancelDate, 121)) from tblProducts
```

below it not a fix - just trying to sort things out

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SFP.Product_Cancellation_Date__c IS NOT NULL 
                 AND cp.MainCode NOT IN ('AYE3', 'AYE4', 'AYE7') 
                 AND SFP.ABC_PRODUCT__c='AYE1' 
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), SFP.Product_Cancellation_Date__c , 121) 
            WHEN SFP.Product_Cancellation_Date__c IS NOT NULL 
                 AND cp.MainCode     IN ('AYE3', 'AYE4', 'AYE7') 
                 AND SFP.ABC_PRODUCT__c='AYE2'  
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), SFP.Product_Cancellation_Date__c, 121) 
            ELSE (select MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), vp.CancelDate, 121)) 
                  from tblProducts)  --HERE IS WHERE MY ISSUE IS
       END as 'xxx'
 FROM [DB_User].[dbo].[Customer] s
 JOIN [EMP].dbo.tblProducts vp 
   ON vp.customerID = s.customerID
  AND                 s.Status='C' 
  AND                 s.CustomerID = '36598758';
 JOIN tblXXProducts cp 
   ON vp.ProductID = cp.ProductID
 JOIN [LINKEDSERVER].CBS.SF.tblRNRProduct__c SFP
   ON SFP.Account_Number__c = CAST(s.CustomerID AS VARCHAR)
  AND SFP.ABC_PRODUCT__c = CASE WHEN cp.MainCode IN ('AYE3','AYE4','AYE7') 
                                THEN 'XYZ' 
                                ELSE 'ERD' 
                           END
```